# How to load a contact sheet of images with PySide?

Tags: python, widget, pyside, qpixmap

The code below loads one image. I wish to load an unknown number of images which resides in a folder and I wish them to show up in a contact sheet kind of manner.

How can I modify the code below so that it will take a list of images and show them side by side?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("myImage.jpg")

        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

        hbox.addWidget(lbl)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Image viewer')
        self.show()        

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might the overall thing that you want including the scrollbars..

```
import os
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.img_fold = r"C:\Users\abhishek.garg\Desktop\New folder"

        self.widget_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.scrollarea = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.widget_layout.addWidget(self.scrollarea)
        self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.widget)

        self.layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        for img in os.listdir(self.img_fold):
            img_path = os.path.join(self.img_fold, img)

            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img_path)
            lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

            self.layout.addWidget(lbl)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Image viewer')
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Oh, this is perfect - I needed scroll bars :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)


        img_fold = "C:/my_contacts"

        for img in os.listdir(img_fold):
            img_path = os.path.join(img_fold, img)

            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img_path)
            lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
            lbl.setPixmap(pixmap)

            hbox.addWidget(lbl)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Image viewer')
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: and i would also recommend you to use grid layout in case you want to make something like a photo album, also you will have to make your box scrollable otherwise you won't be able to use it if it goes off the screen.. make sense??

Comment: Any pointers on how to move forward with a folder containing thousands of images and where you may want to show the window immediately and then have the images populate the window as you can scroll through it?

Comment: i would suggest you to use paging style instead of loading all the images at once, because that is going to be really really heavy, use the stacked widget and add new pages as you click for new page..